# Ebay Listing Auto-Downloads Text File?

Tags: security, ebay

Every time I visit [this listing](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Plano-non-Rx-Clear-Lenses-For-Snapchat-Spectacles-Spectacles-Sold-Separately-/302209762477?_trksid=p2141725.m3641.l6368) (in Safari on Mac), a file is automatically downloaded to my downloads folder. Should I be concerned?

I searched on Google for "Snapchat Spectacles" and clicked the sponsored link to Ebay on the right and then clicked "More Details" on the Ebay listing which automatically downloaded the file and now every time I visit that link it does it again. It doesn't happen on other listings, even ones that come from Google.

Running updated MacOS and Safari. I suspect that this is some kind of Javascript script on the page?

Update: When I "Get Info" -> "More Info" -> "Where From" has a link to [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/v/16LbPGFeDuU?fs=1&hl=en_US) which also causes the file to download and then a comma followed by this [ebaydesc link](http://vi.vipr.ebaydesc.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItemDescV4&item=302209762477&t=1486070645000&tid=10&category=178894&seller=rochesteroptical&excSoj=1&excTrk=1&lsite=0&ittenable=false&domain=ebay.com&descgauge=1) which is apparently known to have a history of directing people to fake logins using iFrames...

--

Not sure if related but clipboard all of a sudden had 3 numbers I didn't recognize, just after all this happened. Could have been my mistake?

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't see any such thing with Chrome on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The listing contains an embedded YouTube video toward the bottom which Safari is not treating like a video, prompting a download. Seems to be a known issue.